# Converting MVC 4 Razor variable into javascript array

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have  a  variable say:

```
var stringArray   = ["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
```

Now  placing this equal to a Javascript  variable like

```
<script>
   var ticks = @stringArray;
</script>
```

But  in variable ticks " is replace with  &quot ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [HtmlHelper.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg568896%28v=vs.111%29.aspx) method to wrap HTML markup in an HtmlString instance so that it is interpreted as HTML markup, or in your case, as JavaScript:

```
<script>
  var ticks = @Html.Raw(stringArray);
</script>
```